# Twig / Symfony 2.3.4: Extending twig template stored in database

Tags: php, database, templates, symfony, twig

I am currently building a CMS in Symfony 2.3.4, and as part of this CMS I would like to store all of the twig templates in a database. I've read up on how to store and access them in the database, and it seems simple enough - however, one question remains. It must be possible to extend templates stored in the database, but I have no idea how to do this.

If anybody has any experience or knowledge I would be very grateful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the guides at the [symfony forum](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=40382&p=131254) and the [Twig Recipes Page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#using-a-database-to-store-templates) I was able to store all the templates in the database, and extending works automatically. Make sure that your isFresh and getCacheKey return values though, otherwise you will get an infinite recursion for some reason.

It is also worth noting that you must add a tag to the database loader service, instead of adding the chain_loader service as the symfony forum suggests.

```
vendor.bundle.twig_database_loader:
    class: Vendor\Bundle\Twig\TwigDatabaseLoader
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.loader }
```

This code will work quite nicely.

Comment: While the above adds some utility, it also appears to greatly increase the number of queries - one for each template regardless of it residing in the file system or a database. Details are in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556354/large-number-of-queries-if-templates-stored-in-database-or-error-on-delete-from). Was the number of queries an issue for you? How about editing templates and clearing the cache?

Comment: @geoB This worked okay for my purposes because templates aren't being constantly created/updated, and there aren't a large amount of templates anyway. I haven't noticed an issue with the number of queries, but then I haven't looked in depth. Long story short, on a small system it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to dive into [Twig_TokenParser_Extends](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/TokenParser/Extends.php#L29) to get an idea of how the `extends` tag works internally.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - turns out my DB loader automatically handles extending the templates. The one time I get lazy and decide to ask before I try and the solution is so simple... However it's always good advice to go through vendor code, you never know what you may find and it always helps understanding.