# Large number of queries if templates stored in database, or error on delete from cache

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

With storing a few templates in a database as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509829/twig-symfony-2-3-4-extending-twig-template-stored-in-database) there is a great increase in the number of database queries.  For example, profiler shows 12 of 20 queries on a page were related to searching for templates although none was stored in the database.  I was under the impression that searches were done only if a template was not available within the file structure.  Is there a method to query the database only if the required template is not in the file structure?

#### Update 1:

Experiments have shown that commenting out the `tags` section of the `vol.volbundle.twig_database_loader` service eliminates the unnecessary queries but can still find a template in the database.  Without the `tags` block the following error occurs

> InvalidArgumentException: Template name "new_opp" is not valid (format
>   is "bundle:section:template.format.engine"

when a template is edited, persisted and an attempt is made to delete its predecessor from cache with the following code. [With the `tags` block present, the cached template is deleted!]  This appears to be the case because the `tags` block allows the database loader to be found during cache delete.

```
    $fileCache = $this->container->get('twig')->getCacheFilename($name);
    if (is_file($fileCache)) {
        @unlink($fileCache);
    }
```

So it is odd, then, that the database loader is used by the controller when the block is not present.

#### services.yml

```
vol.volbundle.twig_database_loader:
    class: Vol\VolBundle\Tools\TwigDatabaseLoader
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.loader }
```

#### TwigDatabaseLoader

```
namespace Vol\VolBundle\Tools;
use \Twig_Error_Loader;
/**
 * Description of DatabaseTwigLoader
 *
 */
class TwigDatabaseLoader implements \Twig_LoaderInterface
{

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getSource($name)
    {
        if (false === $source = $this->getValue('source', $name)) {
            throw new Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Template "%s" does not exist.', $name));
        }

        return $source;
    }

    public function isFresh($name, $time)
    {
        if (false === $lastModified = $this->getValue('last_modified', $name)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $lastModified <= $time;
    }

    public function getCacheKey($name)
    {
// check if exists
        return 'db:' . $name;
    }
    protected function getValue($column, $name)
    {
        $conn = $this->entityManager->getConnection();
        $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT '.$column.' FROM template WHERE name = :name');
        $sth->execute(array(':name' => (string) $name));

        return $sth->fetchColumn();
    }
}
```

#### Compiler

```
namespace Vol\VolBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;

/**
 * Description of TwigDatabaseLoaderPass
 *
 */
class TwigDatabaseLoaderPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('twig');
        $definition->addMethodCall('setLoader', array(new Reference('vol.volbundle.twig_database_loader')));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly relevant is the fact that including a chain loader service as described [here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=40382&p=131254) is not used.  I've tested with and without the service and there's no difference in the number of queries. It is not in my skill set (yet?) to track down why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the large number of queries only occurs in dev mode! This was determined by enabling the query log in MySQL.  Exercising the editing of a template and then rendering it then reviewing the log showed that only the stored template invoked a template query. None of the other templates appeared in the query log. Case closed!