# Cannot review/render edited template stored in database without clearing cache

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

A template stored in a database as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556354/large-number-of-queries-if-templates-stored-in-database), then edited and persisted cannot be rendered for review without clearing the cache, even in dev mode. Once the cache is cleared, the template remains fixed until cache is cleared again.

Presumably there is a method somewhere that allows such an edited template to be available immediately without having to clear the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two options

1) disable the cache on twig:

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

2) remove the cached file when you updated the view on the database:

```
$fileCache = $this->container->get('twig')->getCacheFilename('YourBundle:Default:index.html.twig');

if (is_file($fileCache)) {
    @unlink($fileCache);
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Outstanding!  Thanks.  I used method #2 as it is better targeted.

Comment: Curiously, #2 fails if a small modification is made to a service that allows serving templates from a database.  See `Update 1` in my question on [excessive queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556354/large-number-of-queries-if-templates-stored-in-database) for details

Comment: If you don't update the template there is no need to delete the cached template. The file caches only the twig template. So updating the service there is no need to compile the twig template again.

Comment: To be clearer, I was experimenting with the service to see its effect on the number of queries.  With the modified service the query count was reduced - that was good.  However, I lost the ability to delete the cached template after editing it - not good.

Comment: If I were you I will write a Doctrine Listener (if you are using it) and when you persist the template I will execute the code that deletes the cached template.

Comment: The issue is moot.  Turns out the excess queries occur only in dev mode.  In prod, the above solution is just fine, assuming the `tags` block remains, which it will in prod.